# Run a docker container in Windows

Tags: windows, qemu, boot2docker

I have a Linux x86 application inside a docker container and I want to run it under Windows. I don't want to force users to install Virtual Box. Ideally a [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) or similar virtualization tool can be used, since it is very tiny and requires no installation at all.

My approach was to use [qemu for Windows](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/) and 
[boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker), so I can boot a minimal Linux with docker installed and than run my docker container within it.

This is the command I'm using to run it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 256 -cdrom boot2docker.iso
```

The boot goes well, but I have several problems:

- at every boot the image goes trough all the configuration steps (generating keys for ssh, setting hostname, etc.) that can be skipped the second time the image runs; seems that the changes to the image are not persisted trough runs. I want to build an image that is already configured and needs only to boot;
- to add my application inside the image I have to rebuild the whole `boot2docker.iso` image by using the steps described in [How to build boot2docker.iso locally](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md).

So, the question is: how can I use the base boot2docker.iso image and add some persisting data (such as configurations and my application)? Perhaps a read/write partition mounted from another file?

Comment: like the idea, did u check MobaliveCD http://www.mobatek.net/labs_mobalivecd.html, it seems doesn't support 64bit (which boot2docker needs), but the function fits for you need.

Comment: @LarryCai seems very promising. If you you write an answer, I'll accept it if it works. The only thing missing is a lightweight distribution with docker inside. Maybe boot2docker itself?

Comment: we may cooperate to have a `livedocker` or similar project based on MobaliveCD if license is ok

Comment: @LarryCai yes, maybe a fork of `boot2docker` to be "qemu friendly", such as removing virtual box tools, etc... Than `livedocker` or even `quemu` itself can be used to boot this live image.

Comment: Any success/updates on this? There is an open question on rocker forum https://forums.docker.com/t/install-docker-without-hyperv-virtualbox-vmware-support-on-windows/93641/6

Answer (score 1):

Your command

qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 256 -cdrom boot2docker.iso

launches an ISO, what you want is
reserve some disk place for this iso in a .img

run this iso and install it in this .img

reboot

In a Linux you would start by doing

`qemu-img create -f qcow2 /home/myuser/my_image.img 6G`

There is docker-cli for Windows, it seems to be what you look for, see 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/18/docker-cli-for-windows-clients/

Comment: This will create an empty image file. How can I install boot2docker on it? If I run qemu on it (`qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 256 -cdrom boot2docker.iso -hda my_image.img -boot d`) it keeps booting from the iso and not changing the img. Moreover how can I put my files inside that img?

Comment: In Linux, after creating the .img, you would run something like `kvm -m 256 -cdrom my.iso -boot d image.img` and install using the whole disk (the 6 Giga or the size when you created the .img), here run a similar command with qemu, then reboot `kvm -m 256 image.img`

Comment: You need to do a complete installation of the OS of your .iso in your .img (of course you will only do this once)

Answer (score 1):

like the idea.

Maybe you can check [MobaliveCD](http://mobatek.net/labs_mobalivecd.html), it has a nice lightweight GUI and it embeds qemu system inside. I tried it for [tinycore live cd iso](http://tinycorelinux.net/downloads.html) (base of boot2docker), which works quite ok.

While it seems it doesn't support 64bit (which boot2docker needs), but the function fits for you need.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but still alive today.

Things have changed a lot over the time.

Easiest solution in 2023 is run Docker Desktop for Windows eventually on WSL.

First, you can run `wsl --install` in a privileged powershell and you get a full linux kernel inside windows. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Then, if you install first WSL and then Docker Desktop, then docker runs natively in the linux kernel inside windows. See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

I have friends that run web-apps I have developed with apache, PHP, symfony MySQL and all, and I just tell them the `docker run` command they need (provided they have my image) and that's all.

Usually the setup for my friends is:

- Create volumes for persisting data
- Create a network (so all my stuff runs isolated from other things they run)
- `docker run` some backing services (like MySQL that uses the volume, etc.)
- `docker run` the applications.

I have managed to guide **easily** to **multiple** friends that are **non-tech** and they succeeded.

To pass them the image I don't share any repository. I pass them a binary and we use `docker load` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/ to pass them in the image I want them to run.

About the "configuration" of the image, I pass all via env-vars so no need to recompile anything. Same setup, same image runs for N friends. Just each one runs a `docker run` with different `-e` params.

Docker Desktop for Windows inside WSL runs nealy bare-metal speed. Nearly zero overhead. I run about 20 containers on bootup in my laptop and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use boot2docker http://boot2docker.io/

On boot2docker installation, it will install virtualbox behind the scenes.

You only have to start the boot2docker shortcut and the virtual box management and vms are hidden.

Comment: The question relates to how to do it without using virtual box.

Comment: Ok, going to delete this answer